# How to resolve Security code scan SCS0016 in API controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, csrf, code-analysis, security-code-scan

We have implemented weather API controller to update weather data and inherited `ControllerBase` in API controller with `APIController` action filter like below and enabled security code scan.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SampleApiApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UpdateWeatherDetails")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> PostWeatherDetails(WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
        {
            // Some lines of code to implement
        }
    }
}
```

I can be able to post Json content data, but I Could not able to post data with content type as **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`** in UpdateWeatherDetails API.

To resolve the above issue, I have used **`[FromForm]`** attribute to post form data like below, now I am able to post form data and Json data. But I have faced security warning `SCS0016`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SampleApiApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UpdateWeatherDetails")]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> PostWeather([FromBody] WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
        {
            return PostMethod(weatherForecast);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UpdateWeatherDetails")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> PostWeatherDetails([FromForm] WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
        {
            // Some lines of code to implement
        }
    }
}
```

I thought after adding FromForm attribute only facing security warning and removed it, now no security warning, but I am unable get data binding to parameter. Now,  I have removed **`[ApiController]`** attribute and tried to post form data, Now I am able to post form data.

But I am again getting Security warning** `SCS0016` **for that method.

How to resolve the above `Security` issue and get data send with **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`** working?